# Looking for clarification of std::join behavior

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I've been learning more about multithreading and locking, which has led me to the basic example provided by http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/join/

The basic explanation provided by that page is:

> The function returns when the thread execution has completed.

Okay, so it kind of sounds like we start a thread, and we will resume the calling thread when the thread we started completes.

Here is some example code from the site, that I've added a print statement to.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <unistd.h>

std::mutex mtx;

void print_block (int n, char c) {
    mtx.lock();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << c;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl ;
    mtx.unlock();

    return;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread th1(print_block, 50, '*');
    std::thread th2(print_block, 60, '$');

    th1.join();
    //my print statement
    std::cout << "In between thread joins" << std::endl;
    th2.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Based on the description of join I see, I would expect the output to be:

> **************************************************
>
> In between thread joins
>
> $$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$

My logic is:

1. Main thread calls th1.join, so main thread halts execution until th1.join completes.
2. th1 execution completes after printing out stars, and then my print statement executes
3. th2 execution begins and ends

In reality this isn't the case, th2 can execute before th1, my print statement usually comes out last.  What does join actually do to the main thread?  It doesn't seem to actually block it like I keep reading online.

Regardless, my interpretation makes no sense as it seems like it would be the same as a single threaded process.  Help!

TLDR;

What really happens when you call join?  The new thread begins, but what happens to the main thread?  If the main thread does block, why isn't my example the case?

Thanks

EDIT:

I think I understand.  For some reason I thought that th1 begins executing when join is called.  th1 begins executing when the constructor is called.  Join will block the main thread until th1 is finished after it begins executing.  Thanks everyone!

Comment: What happens with `join`() is exactly what is described to happen. Note, however, nothing in the description of `join()` that you read guarantees you any specific execution order that preceded the join, when multiple execution thread were running, and you're joining to one of them. In fact, the second thread can start, and manage to acquire the mutex before the first one, thus end up running first. There are no guarantees, whatsoever. The shown example is, actually, garbage.

Comment: `th1` & `th2` are running at the same time. By the time `th1` finishes and joins the chances are `th2` has also finished and is waiting for you to join it.

Comment: I don't understand why you expected `th1.join();` to somehow block/prevent execution of `th2`. You launched `th2` *before* calling `th1.join();`. Why do you expect `th2` to somehow "wait" and only start much later?

Comment: hi @AnT please see my new edit.  For some reason I thought that join also began execution of a thread.  The execution begins when you call the constructor.  My mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That example is bad (reasons below);

> What really happens when you call join? The new thread begins, but
>   what happens to the main thread? If the main thread does block, why
>   isn't my example the case?

`th1.join()` will block execution of the *current thread*(in this case the thread of execution in which the function `main()` is running) until the thread of execution represented by `th1` completes and returns.

Now, this is irrespective of whether `th2` completes before `th1` - (there's no guarantee that thread `th1` enters the function and picks the lock before the thread `th2`). All that method is saying is, "*do not continue until `th1` is completed*".

So, yes, `th2` may finish before `th1`, but

```
std::cout << "In between thread joins" << std::endl;
```

will never be executed until `th1` finishes.

---

Bad example:

- With respect to exception safety. Prefer `std::lock_guard`. And please prefer using **[cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/)** henceforth.
- The `std::cout ...` in your `int main()` isn't protected, yes, `std::cout` is free from race, but not free from interleaving the character output when used by multiple threads
- If you need relative ordering between some functions, `std::thread` is probably not what you want to use. And also, prefer higher abstractions such as `std::async`.
- codewise, even if the `std::cout ...` in your `int main()` is assumed to be an indivisible transaction, putting `th1.join()` before it and `th2.join()` after it is just a deceitful. I would have the joins follow each other on code.

Comment: The shown example is actually crap for a completely different reason. It obviously presumes that the first thread will succeed in locking the mutex before the second one. That, obviously, is not true.

Comment: Thanks, I misunderstood that the new thread begins when you call join.  It begins when you call the constructor in this case.  Thanks